# CSS Grid + Flexbox to create new layout for mobile

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I might or might not need flexbox for this issue, but I'm still learning and trying to understand how I can get the `title` to be on top of the `add button`, which should fill about 96% of the row's width under the `title`.
I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pd6spv) to demonstrate current code. Also the desktop version should allow title and add button to occupy same row at `70% 30%` grid like in stackblitz demo.

This is the desired result when you collapse the browser window to mobile

[image]

html

```
<div class="listingBody">
  <div class="listingParent">
    <div class="listingCard">
      <div class="topRow">
        <span id="title">title</span><span 
          id="addButtonSpan">


          <button id="addButton" type="button">
           Add Button</button>

        </span>

      </div>
  
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
#title {
text-align:center;
}

.topRow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would go about it using just flexbox not css grid.

I use a media query to do the mobile stacked layout with `flex-direction: column`

```css
.topRow {
  display: flex;
}

.topRow #title {
  width: 70%;
}

.topRow #addButtonSpan {
  width: 30%;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topRow {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .topRow span {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .topRow #title {
    width: 96%;
  }

  .topRow #addButtonSpan {
    width: 96%;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="listingBody">
  <div class="listingParent">
    <div class="listingCard">
      <div class="topRow">
        <span id="title">title</span>
        <span id="addButtonSpan">
          <button id="addButton" type="button">
            Add Button
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```